# continuous response variable with lots of zero values

Tags: poisson-distribution, mean, continuous-data, univariate

I'm trying to determine the effects of four treatments on flowers on the volume of nectar available to pollinators. Problem is, I have about 50% zero volumes across treatment categories. What is the best approach to comparing mean volumes between treatments?

Comment: If there are "lots of zeros" ... how is it continuous? And if it's continuous, why is "Poisson" one of your tags?

Comment: @Glen_b There could be lots of zeroes and continuous data. E.g. if you asked "total number of miles traveled by air in last 12 months" of a random sample of people (technically, I guess 'miles' is a count, but it would certainly be treated as continuous).  I don't know why 'Poisson' is a tag here though

Comment: @PeterFlom That would be an example of a *mixture* distribution, not an actually *continuous* distribution. The portion that is above zero is continuous, certainly, but the distribution overall is not.

Comment: @Glen_b OK, technically you  are right, but I bet this is the sort of thing that busybee means. He said "continuous response variable", which I think this is, even if it's from a mixture distribution, but I also think this gets a bit pedantic about the semantics.

Comment: @PeterFlom It often makes a difference; for example, if one proposes to use a rank-based technique (it is stated to be *continuous*, so it must be okay, right?) ... but in fact that spike at zero is a problem. Better to be crystal clear about the properties of the random variables are that are at hand than let sloppiness lead us into otherwise easily-avoided errors. For example, if someone really is analyzing flight miles and for those that travel at all, a gamma distribution is a reasonable model, a zero-inflated distribution may work quite well for the overall data, ... (ctd)

Comment: (ctd) ... whereas a straight gamma GLM on the data including zeros will have problems.  So often handwaving away such details as 'just being technical' is eventually the cause of problems. If we do make such compromises in an analysis (treating the [mixed](http://homepage.stat.uiowa.edu/~nshyamal/22S175/DI.pdf) distribution as continuous), let's at least be clear we're doing it. (the link is mainly so I can find it later)

Comment: Of course you can fit a mixture model. However, since you have only "treatment" as independent variable, why not stick to something which is easy to understand for non-stats? Like descriptively comparing (a) the proportions of zero between treatments, (b) comparing means of all non-zero volumes and (c) comparing mean volumes?

Answer (score 2):

There is finite mixture model regression. In `SAS` you can do this with `PROC FMM`, see [this article](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings12/328-2012.pdf); in particular, example 1 deals with excess zeroes in a Poisson model (ZIP) but because of the structure of `FMM` you can substitute `normal` for `poisson` in the code, e.g. something like :

```
proc fmm data= dataset;
model dv = ivs / dist=normal;
model dv = / dist=constant;
probmodel ivs;
run;
```

In `R` there is the [`flexmix` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flexmix/vignettes/flexmix-intro.pdf), which seems to provide similar with the function `FLXMRziglm`.